# Oscillating bus icon: How is it being done?

Tags: html, css

This is something seriously cool, I'd like to implement it:

[image: left]

[image: right]

www.reload.in

I want to replicate the oscillating bus icon at the top panel. My trusty "Inspect Element" won't come to my aid this time.

Has anyone implemented anything similar to this? If so, could you explain what is being done here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by using css animations,

```css
#bus{
  animation-name:anim;
  animation-iteration-count:infinite;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-direction: alternate; 
  width: 50px;
  height: 25px;
  background: tomato;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
}
.container{
  margin-top: 10px;
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  height: 30px;
  background: #ddd;
  padding: 15px;
 }

@keyframes anim{
0%{
   transform:translate(0,0); 
   -webkit-transform:translate(0,0); 
}
  100%{
    transform:translate(400px,0);
    -webkit-transform:translate(400px,0);  
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="bus">
    
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this below code it my help you.

```css
#bustic{
  animation:Floatbus 5s infinite;
  width: 50px;
  height: 25px;
  background: url(https://cdn.reload.in/assetsv2/images/bus_new.png) center top no-repeat;
}


@keyframes Floatbus{
0%{
   transform:translate(0,0); 
   -webkit-transform:translate(0,0); 
}
  100%{
    transform:translate(400px,0);
    -webkit-transform:translate(400px,0);  
  }
}
```

```html
 <div id="bustic">
    
</div>
```

Comment: This is similar, but a different kind of animation. It cycles instead of oscillating.

Comment: as you asked to implement anything similar to that website and also you can try with this code for cyclic.   div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    background: url(https://cdn.reload.in/assetsv2/images/bus_new.png) center top no-repeat;
    animation: example infinite 5s;
}

@keyframes example {
    0%   {left:0px;}
    50%  {left:200px;}
    100% {left:0px;}
}